# Connecting Pendrive used by multiple users

Tags: malware, virus, usb

Tried looking for it but didn't find solution. So basically every once in a while we are getting from our kindergarten an USB pendrive with photos. I am trying to find a way to safely copy the files from there as this pendrive can be used by all parents from our group.

Thought about installing some Linux instance (dual boot, currently have only Windows installed) and using it only for the photos. Would such setup be moderately safe assuming that noone from the group is explicitly trying to hack other parents?

Answer (score 1):

Usually those people are not very tech-savy. Thus there is a high risk that their PCs might be infected and they might spread it unknowingly via attached USB flash drives.

When booting from a Linux Live CD and accessing the data there, the risk could get reduced as with a reboot, changes to the OS are gone and most malware is written for other operating systems. There are things like bad usb and usb killer, though.

This risk could be mitigated for example with a dedicated, encrypted flash drive (e.g. Kingston Data Locker+) that are not as easily forgeable to a bad usb device as the generic dollar tree thumb drive. Non-tech people might have difficulties to operate an encrypted USB stick. But it would also educate them how to protect personal data against theft or loosing the flash drive.

However, I would not accept USB flash media from people that I know that they are not following basic security precautions.

The perfect medium for this is a CD/DVD without autorun. Albeit a bit vintage and can be read by anyone that gets access to it.